# Is it possible for an undergrad to publish in a journal without conducting experiments (using existing data)?

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate

Would it be possible to publish in a decent journal (not ArXiv) without conducting experiments? I was thinking of conducting some correlational research based on existing data (Ex. statistics collected by the government available to the public).

What are my chances of publishing as an undergrad based on existing data? Will journals accept this kind of publication? I am open to suggestions on how to go about doing this and whether it is a worthwhile undertaking?

Comment: You haven't even told us what field you're in, I don't think this question is answerable in its current state. (See [Academia varies](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1212/11365).)

Comment: You are talking about step five before even taking the first step: Deciding on an actual problem you want to investigate. And step zero: Discuss possible subjects with your prof, mentor, whatever.

Comment: Most papers on mathematics don't involve experiments or data gathering.  So the answer to your question is "yes."

Comment: ArXiv isn't a journal, so your premise is a bit like asking, "Would it be possible to buy a decent car (not a bicycle)..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle this is possible, however, when using data collected by somebody else you have to take great care not to produce bad science. Data collection is usualy performed with a certain specific application in mind, and when collecting data you have to make sure that the errors introduced in the collection process do not influence the final result in a way that is important for your purpose. If you use the same data for some other purpose your results will likely be affected by some bias.

So if you want to corelate oil prices with GDP growth, you are fine, but with more complex questions you are in real danger.

Answer (score 2):

First, anybody can potentially publish in journals, no matter the status, if the results are good enough. That said, there are special undergraduate journals (I only know a few examples from mathematics, e. g. SIURO which is SIAM Undergraduate Research Online).

I can't comment on the actual topic you have in mind and it would probably be best for you to find a local advisor who can help you with that.